# Is there a metapackage that includes the full install of Ubuntu?

Tags: 20.04, software-installation, metapackages, minimal-install

I chose the "minimal install" option, so I don't have `libreoffice` and probably other things:

```
# apt list libreoffice
Listing... Done
libreoffice/focal-updates 1:6.4.6-0ubuntu0.20.04.1 amd64
```

`ubuntu-desktop` is installed though:

```
# apt list ubuntu-desktop*
Listing... Done
ubuntu-desktop-minimal/focal-updates,now 1.450.2 amd64 [installed]
ubuntu-desktop/focal-updates,now 1.450.2 amd64 [installed]
```

This also does nothing:

```
# apt install ubuntu-desktop --install-recommends
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
ubuntu-desktop is already the newest version (1.450.2).
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
```

Is there a metapackage that includes the full install of Ubuntu?

Comment: [This question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1319291/how-to-convert-a-minimal-installation-to-a-normal-installation/1319303#1319303) was asked earlier today and has an answer that's similar to what you tried. Maybe try that? It's answered by a pretty highly voted user. You could also add a comment at said answer asking for more information.

Comment: The default setting of apt in Ubuntu is to include 'recommends' and to exclude 'suggests'. Let's check those settings: Please add to your question the complete output of `apt-config dump | grep Recommend` and of `apt-config dump | grep Suggest`

Comment: @user535733 1 and 0

Comment: Hmmm. The '1' means apt should have installed 'recommends' like LibreOffice when you installed `ubuntu-desktop` (even without --install-recommends). On my 20.04 test rig, it works properly. Not sure why it's not working on yours; seems to defy logic. Next step to try is `sudo apt install --reinstall ubuntu-desktop`

Comment: @user535733 Just tried it. it just reinstalled the metapackage (Did not install anything new). Adding  `--install-recommends` makes no difference either. Maybe "reinstall" behaves differently from "install" ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [APT - how to install recommended packages after installing with --no-install-recommends switch?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/724462/apt-how-to-install-recommended-packages-after-installing-with-no-install-rec)

Comment: @muru It doesn't come close to answering the Q. For example, the default installation installs proprietary graphics drivers. Those are not included in `ubuntu-desktop`'s *Recommends* list.

Comment: @bobcat so? That's a decision the installer makes based on the system. That's not codified into the packaging system.

Comment: @muru That's what **this** question is about.

Comment: Then put that in the question. The full install doesn't include proprietary graphics drivers for every system. For those that don't, the recommended packages cover the rest.

Comment: @muru "Is there a metapackage that includes the full install of Ubuntu?" -- seems pretty clear. The non-existence of such a metapackage is in no way implied by [this Q&A](https://askubuntu.com/questions/724462/apt-how-to-install-recommended-packages-after-installing-with-no-install-rec)

Comment: Yes: `ubuntu-desktop`. You somehow installed it without the recommends, so the dupe tells you how to get those recommends and install them.